# How to derive the MLE of Bernoulli?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Likelihood is given by

$$L(\theta | x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n = \bar{x}) = (\theta)^{n \bar{x}} (1-\theta)^{n(1-\bar{x})}$$

log likelihood is

$ln (L) = n \bar{x} \ln(\theta) + n(1-\bar{x})\ln(1-\theta)$

derivative is

$\frac{d ln(L)}{d \theta} = \frac{n \bar{x}}{\theta} - \frac{n(1-\bar{x})}{1-\theta}$

now what? Answer is $\hat{\theta}$= $\bar{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equate the derivative to $0$.

$$\frac{\bar{x}}{\hat{\theta}}=\frac{1-\bar{x}}{1-\hat{\theta}}$$

Cross multiplying,
$$\bar{x}-\hat{\theta} \bar{x}=\hat{\theta} - \hat{\theta}{\bar{x}}$$

Hence $$\hat{\theta} = \bar{x}.$$

Comment: Note that to verify that it is indeed a maximum, $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial\theta}=-\frac{n\bar x}{\theta^2}-\frac{n(1-\bar x)}{(1-\theta)^2}<0.$$

Comment: thanks, I forgot to check the second derivative.